# Android Provider Testing

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-testing

I am trying to test android content providers. I am writing code similar to given here, inserting into a db and then querying the db, 
but sometimes and not always, the returned cursor has 0 rows. What may be the problem?

```
public class MyProviderTestCase extends ProviderTestCase2<MyProvider> {

private MockContentResolver mMockResolver;
    ....
public MyProviderTestCase() {
    super(MyProvider.class, "com.example.MyProvider");
}

protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    mMockResolver = getMockContentResolver();
}

protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();
}

@SmallTest
public void testInsertAndUpdate() {
    ...
    SomeObject someObject = ...;
    Uri insertedUri = mMockResolver.insert(MyrProvider.URI, someObject.createContentValues());

    assertNotNull(insertedUri);
    Log.d("test insert and update and delete:inserteduri", insertedUri+"");

    Cursor c = mMockResolver.query(MyProvider.URI, null, null, null, null);
    assertNotNull(c);

    assertTrue(c.moveToFirst());// This assertion fails sometimes
}
```

}

Comment: when it gives 0 .?your raw is always more then 2.

Comment: when i rerun this code then sometimes the assertion fails and sometimes it passes, and i also see the rows which i add during the test in the main database

Comment: got the solution, I was not not using the getWritableDatabase in the insert/query in correct way.

Comment: ok.so its problem in database...good